# Sniffing Django database query packets

Tags: django, tcpdump

I'm not sure if this is the good place to ask this type of question.

I have the following set up:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': os.environ["DB_NAME"],
        'USER': os.environ["DB_USER"],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ["DB_PASS"],
        'HOST': os.environ["DB_HOST"],
        'PORT': os.environ["DB_PORT"],
    },
}
```

and was able run a query and get the data back:

```
 >>> from app1.models import Facility
 >>> facility = Facility.objects.filter(id=32432148)
 >>> print("NAME:"+facility[0].algo_name)
 NAME:FBNR_LE
 >>> print("FAC_ID:"+facility[0].fac_id)
 FAC_ID:FBNR_LE_BNS
```

What I want to do is to bascally sniff the DB query packets sent from Django over to Postgresql server.

So I run tcpdump for duration of the query:

```
# tcpdump 'tcp port 5432' -w /tmp/tcp_dump.pcap
```

However, the query and the data returned from it can not be found in the output file.
Anyone have idea how I can capture and view Django query packets?